Problem with creating server in pgadmin 4, unable to connect to server
I am trying to create a server and a db in pgadmin 4.
The error message is Unable to connect to server:
connection failed: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections

I created a docker-compose:

version: '3.8'
services:
postgres:
image: postgres:13  # Version de PostgreSQL
container_name: postgres_container
environment:
POSTGRES_USER: admin
POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
POSTGRES_DB: postgres
volumes:
postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
- ../src/scripts/data/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql  # Montez le script
ports:
- "5432:5432"
pgadmin:
image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest  # Image officielle de pgAdmin 4
container_name: pgadmin_container
environment:
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com  # Email de connexion à pgAdmin
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin  # Mot de passe pour pgAdmin
ports:
- "8080:80"  # Expose l'interface pgAdmin sur le port 8080
depends_on:
postgres
volumes:
pgadmin_data:/var/lib/pgadmin
volumes:
postgres_data:
pgadmin_data:

Then I used a init.sql in the right path and docker-compose up.
This question has found an answer

You should use the servicename postgres (embedded docker-DNS) instead of the IP 127.0.0.1 (shown in the error-log) for the pgadmin connection.
